# Horizontal Shif of Facebook button in floating bar under Firefox

Tags: html, css, facebook, firefox, mozilla

I have a floating bar that contains 5 social buttons. Only the Facebook button is shifting about 20 pixels in the left.

In the tens of CSS elements of the button under elements inspector, when I deactivate the `position: absolute;` of the code below, the button goes to its normal place. But I am not sure if it is the appropriate solution since it can affect the beahviour in other browsers.

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Do you have an idea about this problem? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a simplified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: thank you for you quick reply to this matter, I will do it It will take time since I never jsFiddled an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding this to your CSS:

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {
    position: relative !important;
}
```

That should fix it.

I also got this problem today. It seems that Facebook recently made a change to the Like buttons.
I'm adding this code to all my sites with Fb Like buttons now.